# Count and sort by number of occurrences

Tags: underscore.js

I have an array like this:

```
var items = [
  {name: 'popcorn', category: 'snacks'},
  {name: 'nachos', category: 'snacks'},
  ...
  {name: 'coke', category: 'drinks'}
];
```

I want to get a list of categories ordered by the number of items on it (most items first):

```
['snacks', 'drinks']
```

Here is how I did it:

```
var categories = _.chain(items)
  .countBy(function (i) { return i.category })
  .pairs()
  .sortBy(function (c) { return -c[1] })
  .map(function (c) { return c[0] })
  .value();
```

So the result of `countBy` is an object, and I have to use `pairs` to convert it into an array of arrays in order to sort it.

I wonder if there is a more straightforward way to do it? Built-in function?

Comment: You could just pass 'category' into the countBy function. Makes it a teeny weeny bit more expressive.

Comment: Wouldn't the returned value of that look like [ [ 'snacks', 10] [ 'drinks', 9] ]?

Comment: @JSager oops I forgot the map step. Fixed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I wonder if there is a built-in function?

Nope, your approach is fine.

> more straightforward way to do it?

You could shorten it a bit by passing only property names, not functions:

```
var categories = _.chain(items)
  .countBy("category")
  .pairs()
  .sortBy(1).reverse()
  .pluck(0)
  .value();
```

Comment: You can save one step by sorting in descending order straight away rather than sorting ascending and then reversing (Also has the advantage of keeping the order of items with the same count intact)

`var categories = _.chain(items).countBy("category").pairs().sortBy(function(pair) {return -pair[1];}).pluck(0).value();`

(Sorry about the one-liner - struggling to format a code block)

Comment: Yeah, of course you can (and OP already did this), but my point was not to use any callback functions (for shortening the code only).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty good. You could cram it into a one-step reduce but that would wind up being more complicated than what your code looks like now. If you're going to be reusing this a bunch, you could use compose and partial to reduce the overall amount of code you're writing. Also, check out lodash as an alternative to underscore - it's got more juice.